# Wookmark plugin offset and overlap

Tags: jquery

I am using the Wookmark plugin, which is great. But, when watched in Chrome AND Safari, the last item overlaps one of the other items. The weird is when I am hitting CMD+R it's overlapping, but when marking URL and hitting ENTER it doesn't overlap. When watched in Firefox it's never overlapping and everything is fine.

Second is that when using offset, it's applying the full amount of pixels horizontal but not vertical. So I have to add a padding-bottom to the item.

Code

```
$('.post').wookmark({
  container: $('.grid'),
  autoResize: true,
  align: 'left',
  itemWidth: 365,
  offset: 15
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="post" data-id="">

    <div class="post-content rounded-top">
        <header>
            <img class="post-profile-pic rounded" src="<?php ROOT ?>graphic/profile/mette.jpg">
            <div class="post-author-name">Mette-Line Laurvig Nielsen</div>
            <div class="post-stamp">2<?php $print->output('h'); ?> ago</div>
        </header>
        <article>Let's turn up the music! I am very nervous that this won't work in the end. What do you guys think? Please tell me the truth :) And a lot of nervousity.</article>
        <div class="post-details">
            <span class="post-like"><?php $print->output('like'); ?> &nbsp;·&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="post-likes"><i>3</i> <?php $print->output('likes'); ?></span>
            <span class="post-comments-count"><i>17</i> <?php $print->output('comments'); ?></span>
        </div><!-- .post-details -->
    </div><!-- .post-content -->

    <div class="comment-wrap post-comments rounded-top">
    </div><!-- .post-comments -->

    <div class="comment-wrap post-write-comment rounded-bottom">
        <form method="post">
            <textarea class="rounded-bottom" type="text" name="" placeholder="<?php $print->output('write your comment...'); ?>"></textarea>
        </form>
    </div><!-- .post-write-comment -->

</div><!-- .post -->
```

Screenshot: [Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=154capc&s=5)

Comment: add some code and update your question

Comment: Could you 1) post a screenshot of the issue, and 2) paste your code into the question?

Comment: Sure. Hang on a few minutes.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I've added screenshot and js + html now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Looks like you have to give images specific height and width in the img attribute. The offset issue was due to an incorrect value in itemWidth given by me, I apologise.